# Ширина символа в не моноширинном шрифте

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, шрифты

Есть задача печатать этикетки. Проблема в том, что заказчик не хочет использовать моноширинный шрифт, но хочет, чтобы учитывалась ширина символов в не моноширинном шрифте (для определения сколько символов влезет в строку).

Как определить ширину символа в шрифте?

Писать приходится на JS.

upd. спасибо за ответы, мне стоило уточнить сразу, HTML вообще не используется (используется специальная тулзовина "Loftware Label Manager"), есть ли возможность сделать это используя чистый JS?

Comment: Если вы используете HTML canvas, если вам это подходит http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_measuretext.asp

Answer (score 1):

Создать невидимый div с нужным шрифтом и померять ширину. Добавлять по одному символу, пока длина строки не будет превышена. Мерять примерно так:

HTML:

```
<div id="Test">
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Test
{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

JS:

```
var test = document.getElementById("Test");
test.style.fontSize = fontSize;
var height = (test.clientHeight + 1) + "px";
var width = (test.clientWidth + 1) + "px";
```

<sub>пример взят с [enSO, Calculate text width with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript)</sub>